# how to replace vanilla JS "click to show/hide" action with jQuery by changing CSS property

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm following this tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp for a homework question.

The vanilla JS to be replaced with jQuery looks like:

```
document.getElementById('menu-signin').addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementById('blanket').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('signin-box').style.display = 'block';
    });
    document.getElementById('menu-join').addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementById('blanket').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('join-box').style.display = 'block';
    });
    document.getElementById('blanket').addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementById('blanket').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('signin-box').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('join-box').style.display = 'none';
    });
    document.getElementById('cancel-signin-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementById('blanket').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('signin-box').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('join-box').style.display = 'none';
    });
    document.getElementById('cancel-join-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementById('blanket').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('signin-box').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('join-box').style.display = 'none';
    });
```

I tried including the CDN which did not work so downloaded jQuery non-minified version into folder `js` and put this in the `<head></head>`:

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
```

My jQuery to replace the above vanilla JS is:

```
<script>
//show signin on click
    $(document).ready(function()){
        $("#menu-signin").click(function()){
            $("#blanket").css("display", "block")
            $("#signin-box").css("display", "block")
        }
    }
    $(document).ready(function()){
        $("#menu-join").click(function()){
            $("#blanket").css("display", "block")
            $("#join-box").css("display", "block")
        }
    }
    //hide blanket on click
    $(document).ready(function()){
        $("#blanket").click(function()){
            $("#blanket").css("display", "none")
            $("#signin-box").css("display", "none")
            $("#join-box").css("display", "none")
        }
    }

    //hide on cancel
    //hide blanket on click cancel
    $(document).ready(function()){
        $("#cancel-signin-button").click(function()){
            $("#blanket").css("display", "none")
            $("#signin-box").css("display", "none")
            $("#join-box").css("display", "none")
        }
    }
    //hide blanket on click cancel
    $(document).ready(function()){
        $("#cancel-join-button").click(function()){
            $("#blanket").css("display", "none")
            $("#signin-box").css("display", "none")
            $("#join-box").css("display", "none")
        }
    }
</script>
```

It will not show the `blanket` and modals for sign in nor join.

Comment: I know it's only a homework task, but I really recommend **not** learning jQuery in 2020.

Comment: @connexo just use vanilla JS?  My professor is a bit old-fashioned, i.e. taught us Bootstrap 3 and said, "Oh, you can use BS4 there the same thing."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you haven't looked at your console for errors.

You don't need to include `ready` around everything, its just needed to wrap once.

However, the actual error that you will see is you are missing the end `)` for the clicks, and for the ready. Instead that `)` was added after `function` instead of after the end `}`.

I also updated your function to include the jquery functions for hide/show.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu-signin").click(function(){
        $("#blanket").show()
        $("#signin-box").show()
    });

    $("#menu-join").click(function(){
        $("#blanket").show()
        $("#join-box").show()
    });
    $("#blanket").click(function(){
        $("#blanket").hide()
        $("#signin-box").hide()
        $("#join-box").hide()
    });

    $("#cancel-signin-button").click(function(){
        $("#blanket").hide()
        $("#signin-box").hide()
        $("#join-box").hide()
    });

    $("#cancel-join-button").click(function(){
        $("#blanket").hide()
        $("#signin-box").hide()
        $("#join-box").hide()
    });
});
```

Comment: `$(document).ready(function()){` should be `$(document).ready(function() {`. The same error exists in all the handler registrations across the board. You should also point out that error as you copied that from OP's code.

Comment: You forgot that all the callbacks are malformed, `function()){`

Comment: Oops, you are correct @connexo and Emiel. There were so many problems, I missed some. My answer has been updated.

Comment: I'm over-reliant on phpstorm to pick up syntax errors, sorry for this.  is webStorm better for detecting these types of syntax errors?  But that would mean debugging my php in phpstorm then switching over to webstorm.

Comment: @webNoob13, I personally don't use any of that. I use Notepad++ for all of my coding/programming. For javascript errors, I let my browser tell me when I run the code.

Comment: @webNoob13 If you already have access to WebStorm, it's a very good IDE for webdev. Visual Studio Code is the best free alternative, which IMO is at least on-par with WebStorm..